# How to black out everything outside a circle in Open CV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

I am currently trying to black out everything outside a circle.
I am drawing the circle using the following lines of code:

```
cv::Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1])); // CVRound converts floating numbers to integer
int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);                              // Radius is the third parameter [i][0] = x [i][1]= y [i][2] = radius
circle( image, center, 3, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );        // Drawing little circle to Image Center , next Line of Code draws the real circle
circle( image, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );    // Circle(img, center, radius, color, thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)
```

What is the best approach of painting everything of the circly black, if I have a radius and the center of my circle?
Does OpenCV provide an easy mechanism of doing this or should I iterate through all the pixels of my image and depending on the position color them black or not?

Comment: Create a mask image (just draw the circle in white color on a black image with size same as that of your original image), then use bitwise_and() with your image and mask..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Abid for the hint, i ended up with this approach. Everything works fine:

```
cv::Mat src = someMethodThatReturnsSrcImage(); // src Image 
cv::Mat maskedImage; // stores masked Image
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles = someMethodThatReturnsCircles(src);    
cv::Mat mask(srcImageForDimensions.size(),srcImageForDimensions.type());  // create an Mat that has same Dimensons as src
mask.setTo(cv::Scalar(0,0,0));                                            // creates black-Image
    // Add all found circles to mask
for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )                          // iterate through all detected Circles
       {
         cv::Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1])); // CVRound converts floating numbers to integer
         int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);                              // Radius is the third parameter [i][0] = x [i][1]= y [i][2] = radius
         cv::circle( mask, center, radius, cv::Scalar(255,255,255),-1, 8, 0 );    // Circle(img, center, radius, color, thickness=1, lineType=8, shift=0)
       }

src.copyTo(maskedImage,mask); // creates masked Image and copies it to maskedImage
```

Answer (score 3):

you can make the background the color you want

```
image=cv::Scalar(red_value, green_value, blue_value);
```

then draw your circles

Answer (score 1):

I think that comment just under your question is the best solution.
I made a modified version of your code for 5M image from fisheye camera. This image also needs to make black all points outside circle.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Vfw.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>    
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgcodecs\imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"    
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;    
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat im_source_non_square = cv::imread("D:/FishLib/sample_02.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    cv::namedWindow("Image",CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
    cv::imshow("Image", im_source_non_square);
    Mat im_source_square;
    int m_nCenterX=1280;
    int m_nCenterY=960;
    int m_nRadius=916;
    Mat im_mask=im_source_non_square.clone();
    im_mask.setTo(cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
    circle( im_mask, cv::Point(m_nCenterX,m_nCenterY), m_nRadius, cv::Scalar(255,255,255), -3, 8, 0 );
    cv::namedWindow("Mask image",CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
    cv::imshow("Mask image", im_mask);
    Mat im_source_circle;
    cv::bitwise_and(im_source_non_square,im_mask,im_source_circle);
    cv::namedWindow("Combined image",CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
    cv::imshow("Combined image", im_source_circle);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your code snippet and it works.
Also if you want to change the background color instead of black, according to opencv docs [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=clone#mat-copyto), before `copyTo` the destination mat will be initialized if needed, so just add code below:

```
cv::Mat maskedImage(srcImageForDimensions.size(), srcImageForDimensions.type()); // stores masked Image 
maskedImage.setTo(cv::Scalar(0,0,255)); // set background color to red
```