# Extract pixels within given cordinates

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to image processing and development. I have pixel coordinates of an image. By connecting each coordinate can be obtained a triangle. I want to extract pixels inside pixels of giving coordinates (pixels within a triangle)

Cordinates as follows.

```
1(x,y) -> (146 , 548)
2(x,y) -> (155, 548)
3(x,y) -> (149.6 , 558.1)
```

How do i take pixels that are inbound of above coordinates. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: first draw a contour with three points using  drawContours method then use that image as mask to extract the pixels.

Comment: @hariprasad could you please explain more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should apply mask on your image.

Example code:

First you should load your image:

```
//load default image
Mat image = cv::imread("/home/fabio/code/lena.jpg", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

[image: default image loaded]

Then create a mask for your image and apply the triangle points to the mask.

```
//mask image definition
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());

//triangle definition (example points)
vector<Point> points;
points.push_back( Point(100,70));
points.push_back( Point(60,150));
points.push_back( Point(190,120));

//apply triangle to mask
fillConvexPoly( mask, points, Scalar( 255 ));
```

After that your mask will look like this:

[image: triangle mask image]

Finally create the final image applying the mask to the original image:

```
//final image definition
cv::Mat finalImage = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), image.type());

image.copyTo(finalImage, mask);
```

Result:

[image: result]

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yap this is correct.Thank you further  How could i take only triangle without background.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread talking about this, the solution given there is easily applicable to your case, just replacing the shape used in the example provided.

Here is the link : [opencv-binary-image-mask-for-image-analysis-in-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554187/opencv-binary-image-mask-for-image-analysis-in-c)